# Embedded web servers

Tags: multithreading, webserver, embed, mongoose-web-server

What are the web-servers that meet at least part of the following requirements:

- multithreading
- receives scattered request headers
- can cause an external DLL
- capable of processing large data (50 gigabytes or more)
- embedded

Some requirements are met by the Mongoose web-server, are there any other similar technologies?

Comment: What is a scattered request header?

Comment: @valenok read request headers for subsequent processing of the received data.